# How to reproduce checked checkboxes when form is not submitted

Tags: php, checkbox, dynamic

I have form with several check boxes and I want to keep track of which ones are checked on submission, so that when the form is not submitted, I can still reproduce the same check box checks.

This is my code, and in comments what I have tried so far:

```
<div class="control-group">                         
    <label class="control-label">Course</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php
        $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_course";
        $st=$db->prepare($sql);
        $st->execute();
        while($coursers=$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $rs=$coursers['course'];
            $idrs=$coursers['id'];
        ?>
            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="coursecheck[]" value="<?php
            echo $idrs; 
            ?> " 
            <?php
            /*   $array_name=compact($idrs);
                $_SESSION['assign']=ass($post['coursecheck']);
            if(in_array($array_name,$_SESSION['assign']))
            {
                "checked";
            } */ ?>
            />
            <?php echo $rs; ?>
            </label>
        <?php } ?>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Please read the FAQ on how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @Khaja Kadar, welcome on StackOverflow. I have added introductory text to your code, to explain what you were doing in the commented-out code. It is best that you always ask a clear question (not only in the title) and explain what you want to achieve clearly. You should not expect people to scan your code to find out what you actually wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The attempted code that you put in comments, is going in the right direction.

You have to make sure you have created a session, and you should populate the session variable every time the form *is* submitted, so that you can reproduce the checks when the form is not submitted.

Note also you can write `<?= ?>` instead of `<?php echo ?>`.

Here is the suggested code (I did not repeat the `div` tags):

```
<?php
// make sure you have a session:
session_start();
// set the "coursecheck" session variable
if (isset($_post['coursecheck'])) {
    // form was submitted, take the checkbox checks
    $_session["coursecheck"] = $_post['coursecheck'];
} elseif (!isset($_session["coursecheck"])) {
    // we don't have the information, make empty array
    $_session["coursecheck"] = array();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_course";
$st=$db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
while($coursers=$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $rs=$coursers['course'];
    $idrs=$coursers['id'];
?>
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="coursecheck[]"
           value="<?=$idrs?>"
           <?=in_array($idrs, $_session['coursecheck']) ? "checked" : ""?>
    />
    <?= $rs ?>
    </label>
<?php
}
?>
```